# Using Unity3D's IPointerDownHandler approach, but with "the whole screen"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

In Unity say you need to detect finger touch (finger drawing) on something in the scene.

The only way to do this **in modern Unity, is very simple**:

---

**Step 1**. Put a collider on that object. ("The ground" or whatever it may be.) <sup>1</sup>

**Step 2.** On your camera, Inspector panel, click to add a Physics Raycaster (2D or 3D as relevant).

**Step 3.** Simply use code as in Example A below.

*(Tip - don't forget to ensure there's an EventSystem ... sometimes Unity adds one automatically, sometimes not!)*

---

Fantastic, couldn't be easier. Unity finally handles un/propagation correctly through the UI layer.  Works uniformly and flawlessly on desktop, devices, Editor, etc etc. Hooray Unity.

All good. But what if you want to draw just **"on the screen"**?

So you are wanting, quite simply, swipes/touches/drawing from the user "on the screen".   (Example, simply for operating an orbit camera, say.) So just as in any ordinary 3D game where the camera runs around and moves.

You don't want the position of the finger on **some object** in world space, you simply want abstract "finger motions" (i.e. position on the glass).

What collider do you then use? Can you do it with no collider?  It seems fatuous to add a collider just for that reason.

**What we do is this**:

I just make a flat collider of some sort, and actually attach it **under the camera**.  So it simply sits in the camera frustum and completely covers the screen.

[image]

(For the code, there is then no need to use ScreenToWorldPoint, so just use code as in Example B - extremely simple, works perfectly.)

My question, it seems a bit odd to have to use the "under-camera colldier" I describe, just to get touches on the glass.

What's the deal here?

(Note -  please don't answer involving Unity's ancient "Touches" system, which is unusable today for real projects, you can't ignore .UI using the legacy approach.)

---

Code sample A - drawing on a scene object. Use ScreenToWorldPoint.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

 public class FingerMove:MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
 {
     public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data)
     {
         Debug.Log("FINGER DOWN");
         prevPointWorldSpace =
                 theCam.ScreenToWorldPoint( data.position );
     }

     public void OnDrag (PointerEventData data)
     {
         thisPointWorldSpace =
                theCam.ScreenToWorldPoint( data.position );
         realWorldTravel =
                thisPointWorldSpace - prevPointWorldSpace;
         _processRealWorldtravel();
         prevPointWorldSpace = thisPointWorldSpace;
     }

     public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData data)
     {
         Debug.Log("clear finger...");
     }
```

Code sample B ... you only care about what the user does on the glass screen of the device.  Even easier here:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

 public class FingerMove:MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
 {
     private Vector2 prevPoint;
     private Vector2 newPoint;
     private Vector2 screenTravel;

     public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data)
     {
         Debug.Log("FINGER DOWN");
         prevPoint = data.position;
     }

     public void OnDrag (PointerEventData data)
     {
         newPoint = data.position;
         screenTravel = newPoint - prevPoint;
         prevPoint = newPoint;
         _processSwipe();
     }

     public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData data)
     {
         Debug.Log("FINEGR UP...");
     }

     private void _processSwipe()
     {
         // your code here
         Debug.Log("screenTravel left-right.. " + screenTravel.x.ToString("f2"));
     }
 }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're just new to Unity: at that step very likely, make it a layer called say "Draw"; in physics settings make "Draw" interact with nothing; in step two with the Raycaster just set the layer to "Draw".

Comment: So in your explicit use case, you want to utilise the whole screen and avoid the UI interaction as well without using the fake collider. Did I get it right?

Comment: Why would a UI panel or the Input.touches be wrong? Maybe explaining why you don't want those can help.

Comment: HI Ev, input.touches is completely useless, it does not un/propagate through UI correctly.  (The whole basic and most famous problem of Unity is that they totally forgot to block touch events from propagating through Unity.UI. This led to billions of man-hours of programming trying to work around that problem, heh [example of zillions of QA from that era](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/784617/how-do-i-block-touch-events-from-propagating-throu.html). Unity, finally, fixed this with the PhysicsRaycaster which we all use now as the most basic element of Unity.)  Regarding ...

Comment: I understand the problem with using `Input` API for raycasting. The solution here seems to be either the `Input` API or a UI panel with its `Image` color alpha set to 0. And to make sure there is no drawback, the `Image`'s *Source Image* slot should be changed to *None*.

Comment: Dude I just don't see using .UI as a serious solution: imagine we're doing a big game and you're leading a team that is doing all the UI (I mean buttons, menus and all).  I'm leading a team doing the walking robots.  I suddenly say to you "oh, by the way, I **can't handle touch** ("!"), could you drop in a UI.Panel, don't forget to keep it under everything you're doing, oh and put one on any/all canvasses or cameras you swap between - and pass that info back to me OK!"  :)  I mean it's just silly.  One can't essentially say: "oh, Unity **doesn't handle touch**" - !

Comment: BTW I've thought of just using a whole separate camera for screen-touch. I mean that would work and is tidy, but seems inefficient.  But, maybe it's best and cleanest.  It seems incredible there aren't calls like IPointerDownHandler that simply work "on the glass" rather than on a collider.

Comment: if adding extra camera does not affect performance then go for it. I don't know if it affects camera or not.

Comment: I appreciate that but, since it's one of the most absolutely basic things you can do / need to do if you "work with devices" (ie: "we live in the touch screen era") it seems incredible, astounding, there is not some central basic normal approach to this???  I mean WTF?

Comment: So what we basically want is to get raw access to the events send by EventSystem without specific attachment to any GameObjects (as it currently is). Seems to me our options atm are to either use the UI panel hack, or to extend either EventSystem or Input Module. Please tell me if anyone has figured out a sane way for this.

Comment: @Zael - that seems exactly correct, what you say.

Comment: It does seem "totally incredible" they didn't think of this, you know.  We may be missing something.

Comment: Amazing there is still no way to do this - even for a bounty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub><sup>*The question and the answer I am going to post seems pretty much opinion based. Nevertheless I am going to answer as best as I can.*</sup></sub>

If you are trying to detect pointer events on the screen, there is nothing wrong with representing the screen with an object. In your case, you use a 3D collider to cover the entire frustum of the camera. However, there is a native way to do this in Unity, using a 2D UI object that covers the entire screen. The screen can be best represented by a 2D object. For me, this seems like a natural way to do it.

I use a generic code for this purpose:

```
public class Screen : MonoSingleton<Screen>, IPointerClickHandler, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IScrollHandler {
    private bool holding = false;
    private PointerEventData lastPointerEventData;

    #region Events
    public delegate void PointerEventHandler(PointerEventData data);

    static public event PointerEventHandler OnPointerClick = delegate { };

    static public event PointerEventHandler OnPointerDown = delegate { };
    /// <summary> Dont use delta data as it will be wrong. If you are going to use delta, use OnDrag instead. </summary>
    static public event PointerEventHandler OnPointerHold = delegate { };
    static public event PointerEventHandler OnPointerUp = delegate { };

    static public event PointerEventHandler OnBeginDrag = delegate { };
    static public event PointerEventHandler OnDrag = delegate { };
    static public event PointerEventHandler OnEndDrag = delegate { };
    static public event PointerEventHandler OnScroll = delegate { };
    #endregion

    #region Interface Implementations
    void IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick(PointerEventData e) {
        lastPointerEventData = e;
        OnPointerClick(e);
    }

    // And other interface implementations, you get the point
    #endregion

    void Update() {
        if (holding) {
            OnPointerHold(lastPointerEventData);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Screen` is a singleton, because there is only one screen in the context of the game. Objects(like camera) subscribe to its pointer events, and arrange theirselves accordingly. This also keeps single-responsibility intact.

You would use this as appending it to an object that represents the so called glass (surface of the screen). If you think buttons on the UI as popping out of the screen, glass would be under them. For this, the glass has to be the first child of the `Canvas`. Of course, the `Canvas` has to be rendered in screen space for it to make sense.

One hack here, which doesn't make sense is to add an invisible `Image` component to the glass, so it would receive events. This acts like the raycast target of the glass.

[image: Hierarchy]
[image: Inspector]

You could also use `Input` (`Input.touches` etc.) to implement this glass object. It would work as checking if the input changed in every `Update` call. This seems like a polling-based approach to me, whereas the above one is an event-based approach.

Your question seems as if looking for a way to justify using the `Input` class. IMHO, Do not make it harder for yourself. Use what works. And accept the fact that Unity is not perfect.

Comment: I can also include the full code for this `Screen` class. Also, you probably don't want to name it `Screen` because it would conflict with Unity's.

Comment: @JoeBlow You were using a 3D object to represent something that is always in front of camera and always have the same position on screen. Well, that is the screen. To answer your question, yes it seems odd to use a 3D object, but not when you use a UI object. For your 2nd comment: As I said, the glass is under every object on the UI, you can't touch the glass when there is a paper on it, right? It may not be convenient, but it is the natural way. That is just my opinion tho. In some cases, there will also be objects under the glass. See how internet maps are implemented for a concrete example.

Comment: By the way, unrelatedly - **WAIT!  I HAVE GOOD NEWS!**  You know how on the panel you use an invisible image, because Unity forgot to make a Touchable component.  **THERE'S A COMMON BETTER SOLUTION FOR THAT NOW!** http://stackoverflow.com/a/36892803/294884

Comment: @JoeBlow Yeah but you have all rights to disagree as this is all opinion and preference based. Also I never had experience working with multiple Canvas so I have no idea how to answer it. We just have to experiment. That Touchable thing is a gem, good hack, never noticed it before.

Comment: Right, the `Touchable` thing is brilliant.  A guy on the old unity list came up with it and I tidied it up a bit and it's widely used now, it's so handy.  You're quite right - what's needed here is someone to experiment with multiple Canvas, and maybe even more than one camera, a camera just for that.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you need to understand that there are just `3` ways to detect click on an Object with the `OnPointerDown` function:

**1**.You need a UI component to in order to detect click with the `OnPointerDown` function. This applies to other similar UI events.

**2**.Another method to detect a click with the `OnPointerDown` function on a 2D/Sprite GameObject is to attach `Physics2DRaycaster` to the Camera and then `OnPointerDown`  will be called when it is clicked. Note that a *2D Collider* must be attached to it.

**3**.If this is a 3D Object with a Collider not *2D Collider*, you must have `PhysicsRaycaster` attached to the camera in order for the `OnPointerDown` function to be called.

Doing this with the first method seems more reasonable instead of having a large collider or 2D collider covering the screen. All you do is to create a `Canvas`, Panel GameObject, and attach `Image` component that stretches across the whole screen to it.

> Dude I just don't see using .UI as a serious solution: imagine we're
>   doing a big game and you're leading a team that is doing all the UI (I
>   mean buttons, menus and all). I'm leading a team doing the walking
>   robots. I suddenly say to you "oh, by the way, I can't handle touch
>   ("!"), could you drop in a UI.Panel, don't forget to keep it under
>   everything you're doing, oh and put one on any/all canvasses or
>   cameras you swap between - and pass that info back to me OK!" :) I
>   mean it's just silly. One can't essentially say: "oh, Unity doesn't
>   handle touch"

Not really hard like the way you described it. You can write a long code that will be able to create a `Canvas`, `Panel` and an `Image`. Change the image alpha to `0`. All you have to do is attach that code to the Camera or an empty GameObject and it will perform all this for you automatically on play mode.

Make every GameObject that wants to receive event on the screen subscribe to it, then use `ExecuteEvents.Execute` to send the event to all the interfaces in the script attached to that GameObject.

For example, the sample code below will send `OnPointerDown` event to the GameObject called target.

```
ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerDownHandler>(target,
                              eventData,
                              ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
```

**Problem you will run into**:

The hidden `Image` component will block other UI or GameObject from receiving raycast. This is the biggest problem here.

**Solution**:

Since it will cause some blocking problems, it is better to make the Canvas of the Image to be on top of everything. This will make sure that it is now 100 blocking all other UI/GameObject. `Canvas.sortingOrder = 12;` should help us do this.

Each time we detect an event such as `OnPointerDown` from the Image, we will **manually** send resend the `OnPointerDown` event to all other UI/GameObjects beneath the `Image`.

First of all, we throw a raycast with `GraphicRaycaster`(UI), `Physics2DRaycaster`(2D collider), `PhysicsRaycaster`(3D Collider) and store the result in a `List`.

Now, we loop over the result in the List and resend the event we received by sending artificial event to the results with:

```
ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerDownHandler>(currentListLoop,
                              eventData,
                              ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
```

**Other problems you will run into**:

You won't be able to send emulate events on the `Toggle` component with  `GraphicRaycaster`. This is a [bug](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1248512/graphicraycaster-seems-to-ignore-toggle-elements.html) in Unity. It took me 2 days to realize this.

Also was not able to send fake slider move  event to the `Slider` component. I can't tell if this is a bug or not.

Other than these problems mentioned above, I was able to implement this. It comes in **3** parts. Just create a folder and put all the scripts in them.

**SCRIPTS**:

**1**.*`WholeScreenPointer.cs`* - The main part of the script that creates `Canvas`, GameObject, and hidden `Image`. It does all the complicated stuff to make sure that the `Image` always covers the screen. It also sends event to all the subscribe GameObject.

```
public class WholeScreenPointer : MonoBehaviour
{
    //////////////////////////////// SINGLETON BEGIN  ////////////////////////////////
    private static WholeScreenPointer localInstance;

    public static WholeScreenPointer Instance { get { return localInstance; } }
    public EventUnBlocker eventRouter;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (localInstance != null && localInstance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            localInstance = this;
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////////// SINGLETON END  ////////////////////////////////


    //////////////////////////////// SETTINGS BEGIN  ////////////////////////////////
    public bool simulateUIEvent = true;
    public bool simulateColliderEvent = true;
    public bool simulateCollider2DEvent = true;

    public bool hideWholeScreenInTheEditor = false;
    //////////////////////////////// SETTINGS END  ////////////////////////////////


    private GameObject hiddenCanvas;

    private List<GameObject> registeredGameobjects = new List<GameObject>();

    //////////////////////////////// USEFUL FUNCTIONS BEGIN  ////////////////////////////////
    public void registerGameObject(GameObject objToRegister)
    {
        if (!isRegistered(objToRegister))
        {
            registeredGameobjects.Add(objToRegister);
        }
    }

    public void unRegisterGameObject(GameObject objToRegister)
    {
        if (isRegistered(objToRegister))
        {
            registeredGameobjects.Remove(objToRegister);
        }
    }

    public bool isRegistered(GameObject objToRegister)
    {
        return registeredGameobjects.Contains(objToRegister);
    }

    public void enablewholeScreenPointer(bool enable)
    {
        hiddenCanvas.SetActive(enable);
    }
    //////////////////////////////// USEFUL FUNCTIONS END  ////////////////////////////////

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        makeAndConfigWholeScreenPinter(hideWholeScreenInTheEditor);
    }

    private void makeAndConfigWholeScreenPinter(bool hide = true)
    {
        //Create and Add Canvas Component
        createCanvas(hide);

        //Add Rect Transform Component
        //addRectTransform();

        //Add Canvas Scaler Component
        addCanvasScaler();

        //Add Graphics Raycaster Component
        addGraphicsRaycaster();

        //Create Hidden Panel GameObject
        GameObject panel = createHiddenPanel(hide);

        //Make the Image to be positioned in the middle of the screen then fix its anchor
        stretchImageAndConfigAnchor(panel);

        //Add EventForwarder script
        addEventForwarder(panel);

        //Add EventUnBlocker
        addEventRouter(panel);

        //Add EventSystem and Input Module
        addEventSystemAndInputModule();
    }

    //Creates Hidden GameObject and attaches Canvas component to it
    private void createCanvas(bool hide)
    {
        //Create Canvas GameObject
        hiddenCanvas = new GameObject("___HiddenCanvas");
        if (hide)
        {
            hiddenCanvas.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
        }

        //Create and Add Canvas Component
        Canvas cnvs = hiddenCanvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        cnvs.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
        cnvs.pixelPerfect = false;

        //Set Cavas sorting order to be above other Canvas sorting order
        cnvs.sortingOrder = 12;

        cnvs.targetDisplay = 0;

        //Make it child of the GameObject this script is attached to
        hiddenCanvas.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    }

    private void addRectTransform()
    {
        RectTransform rctrfm = hiddenCanvas.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    //Adds CanvasScaler component to the Canvas GameObject 
    private void addCanvasScaler()
    {
        CanvasScaler cvsl = hiddenCanvas.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        cvsl.uiScaleMode = CanvasScaler.ScaleMode.ScaleWithScreenSize;
        cvsl.referenceResolution = new Vector2(800f, 600f);
        cvsl.matchWidthOrHeight = 0.5f;
        cvsl.screenMatchMode = CanvasScaler.ScreenMatchMode.MatchWidthOrHeight;
        cvsl.referencePixelsPerUnit = 100f;
    }

    //Adds GraphicRaycaster component to the Canvas GameObject 
    private void addGraphicsRaycaster()
    {
        GraphicRaycaster grcter = hiddenCanvas.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
        grcter.ignoreReversedGraphics = true;
        grcter.blockingObjects = GraphicRaycaster.BlockingObjects.None;
    }

    //Creates Hidden Panel and attaches Image component to it
    private GameObject createHiddenPanel(bool hide)
    {
        //Create Hidden Panel GameObject
        GameObject hiddenPanel = new GameObject("___HiddenPanel");
        if (hide)
        {
            hiddenPanel.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
        }

        //Add Image Component to the hidden panel
        Image pnlImg = hiddenPanel.AddComponent<Image>();
        pnlImg.sprite = null;
        pnlImg.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0); //Invisible
        pnlImg.material = null;
        pnlImg.raycastTarget = true;

        //Make it child of HiddenCanvas GameObject
        hiddenPanel.transform.SetParent(hiddenCanvas.transform);
        return hiddenPanel;
    }

    //Set Canvas width and height,to matach screen width and height then set anchor points to the corner of canvas.
    private void stretchImageAndConfigAnchor(GameObject panel)
    {
        Image pnlImg = panel.GetComponent<Image>();

        //Reset postion to middle of the screen
        pnlImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        //Stretch the Image so that the whole screen is totally covered
        pnlImg.rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
        pnlImg.rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
        pnlImg.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    }

    //Adds EventForwarder script to the Hidden Panel GameObject 
    private void addEventForwarder(GameObject panel)
    {
        EventForwarder evnfwdr = panel.AddComponent<EventForwarder>();
    }

    //Adds EventUnBlocker script to the Hidden Panel GameObject 
    private void addEventRouter(GameObject panel)
    {
        EventUnBlocker evtrtr = panel.AddComponent<EventUnBlocker>();
        eventRouter = evtrtr;
    }

    //Add EventSystem
    private void addEventSystemAndInputModule()
    {
        //Check if EventSystem exist. If it does not create and add it
        EventSystem eventSys = FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>();
        if (eventSys == null)
        {
            GameObject evObj = new GameObject("EventSystem");
            EventSystem evs = evObj.AddComponent<EventSystem>();
            evs.firstSelectedGameObject = null;
            evs.sendNavigationEvents = true;
            evs.pixelDragThreshold = 5;
            eventSys = evs;
        }

        //Check if StandaloneInputModule exist. If it does not create and add it
        StandaloneInputModule sdlIpModl = FindObjectOfType<StandaloneInputModule>();
        if (sdlIpModl == null)
        {
            sdlIpModl = eventSys.gameObject.AddComponent<StandaloneInputModule>();
            sdlIpModl.horizontalAxis = "Horizontal";
            sdlIpModl.verticalAxis = "Vertical";
            sdlIpModl.submitButton = "Submit";
            sdlIpModl.cancelButton = "Cancel";
            sdlIpModl.inputActionsPerSecond = 10f;
            sdlIpModl.repeatDelay = 0.5f;
            sdlIpModl.forceModuleActive = false;
        }
    }

    /*
     Forwards Handler Event to every GameObject that implements  IDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler interface
     */

    public void forwardDragEvent(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Route and send the event to UI and Colliders
        for (int i = 0; i < registeredGameobjects.Count; i++)
        {
            ExecuteEvents.Execute<IDragHandler>(registeredGameobjects[i],
                                    eventData,
                                    ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
        }

        //Route and send the event to UI and Colliders
        eventRouter.routeDragEvent(eventData);
    }

    public void forwardPointerDownEvent(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Send the event to all subscribed scripts
        for (int i = 0; i < registeredGameobjects.Count; i++)
        {
            ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerDownHandler>(registeredGameobjects[i],
                              eventData,
                              ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
        }

        //Route and send the event to UI and Colliders
        eventRouter.routePointerDownEvent(eventData);
    }

    public void forwardPointerUpEvent(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Send the event to all subscribed scripts
        for (int i = 0; i < registeredGameobjects.Count; i++)
        {
            ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerUpHandler>(registeredGameobjects[i],
                    eventData,
                    ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
        }

        //Route and send the event to UI and Colliders
        eventRouter.routePointerUpEvent(eventData);
    }
}
```

**2**.*`EventForwarder.cs`* - It simply receives any event from the hidden `Image` and passes it to the `WholeScreenPointer.cs` script for processing.

```
public class EventForwarder : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    WholeScreenPointer wcp = null;
    void Start()
    {
        wcp = WholeScreenPointer.Instance;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        wcp.forwardDragEvent(eventData);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        wcp.forwardPointerDownEvent(eventData);
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        wcp.forwardPointerUpEvent(eventData);
    }
}
```

**3**.*`EventUnBlocker.cs`* - It unblocks the the rays the hidden `Image` is blocking by sending fake event to any Object above it. Be it UI, 2D or 3D collider.

```
public class EventUnBlocker : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<GraphicRaycaster> grRayCast = new List<GraphicRaycaster>(); //UI
    List<Physics2DRaycaster> phy2dRayCast = new List<Physics2DRaycaster>(); //Collider 2D (Sprite Renderer)
    List<PhysicsRaycaster> phyRayCast = new List<PhysicsRaycaster>(); //Normal Collider(3D/Mesh Renderer)

    List<RaycastResult> resultList = new List<RaycastResult>();

    //For Detecting button click and sending fake Button Click to UI Buttons
    Dictionary<int, GameObject> pointerIdToGameObject = new Dictionary<int, GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void sendArtificialUIEvent(Component grRayCast, PointerEventData eventData, PointerEventType evType)
    {
        //Route to all Object in the RaycastResult
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
        {
            /*Do something if it is NOT this GameObject. 
             We don't want any other detection on this GameObject
             */

            if (resultList[i].gameObject != this.gameObject)
            {
                //Check if this is UI
                if (grRayCast is GraphicRaycaster)
                {
                    //Debug.Log("UI");
                    routeEvent(resultList[i], eventData, evType, true);
                }

                //Check if this is Collider 2D/SpriteRenderer
                if (grRayCast is Physics2DRaycaster)
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Collider 2D/SpriteRenderer");
                    routeEvent(resultList[i], eventData, evType, false);
                }

                //Check if this is Collider/MeshRender
                if (grRayCast is PhysicsRaycaster)
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Collider 3D/Mesh");
                    routeEvent(resultList[i], eventData, evType, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Creates fake PointerEventData that will be used to make PointerEventData for the callback functions
    PointerEventData createEventData(RaycastResult rayResult)
    {
        PointerEventData fakeEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        fakeEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast = rayResult;
        return fakeEventData;
    }

    private void routeEvent(RaycastResult rayResult, PointerEventData eventData, PointerEventType evType, bool isUI = false)
    {
        bool foundKeyAndValue = false;

        GameObject target = rayResult.gameObject;

        //Make fake GameObject target
        PointerEventData fakeEventData = createEventData(rayResult);


        switch (evType)
        {
            case PointerEventType.Drag:

                //Send/Simulate Fake OnDrag event
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IDragHandler>(target, fakeEventData,
                          ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
                break;

            case PointerEventType.Down:

                //Send/Simulate Fake OnPointerDown event
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerDownHandler>(target,
                         fakeEventData,
                          ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);

                //Code Below is for UI. break out of case if this is not UI
                if (!isUI)
                {
                    break;
                }
                //Prepare Button Click. Should be sent in the if PointerEventType.Up statement
                Button buttonFound = target.GetComponent<Button>();

                //If pointerId is not in the dictionary add it
                if (buttonFound != null)
                {
                    if (!dictContains(eventData.pointerId))
                    {
                        dictAdd(eventData.pointerId, target);
                    }
                }

                //Bug in Unity with GraphicRaycaster  and Toggle. Have to use a hack below
                //Toggle Toggle component
                Toggle toggle = null;
                if ((target.name == "Checkmark" || target.name == "Label") && toggle == null)
                {
                    toggle = target.GetComponentInParent<Toggle>();
                }

                if (toggle != null)
                {
                    //Debug.LogWarning("Toggled!: " + target.name);
                    toggle.isOn = !toggle.isOn;
                    //Destroy(toggle.gameObject);
                }
                break;

            case PointerEventType.Up:

                //Send/Simulate Fake OnPointerUp event
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerUpHandler>(target,
                        fakeEventData,
                        ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);

                //Code Below is for UI. break out of case if this is not UI
                if (!isUI)
                {
                    break;
                }

                //Send Fake Button Click if requirement is met
                Button buttonPress = target.GetComponent<Button>();

                /*If pointerId is in the dictionary, check 

                 */
                if (buttonPress != null)
                {
                    if (dictContains(eventData.pointerId))
                    {
                        //Check if GameObject matches too. If so then this is a valid Click
                        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GameObject tempButton = resultList[i].gameObject;
                            if (tempButton != this.gameObject && dictContains(eventData.pointerId, tempButton))
                            {
                                foundKeyAndValue = true;
                                //Debug.Log("Button ID and GameObject Match! Sending Click Event");

                                //Send/Simulate Fake Click event to the Button
                                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerClickHandler>(tempButton,
                                      new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current),
                                      ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        //Remove pointerId since it exist 
        if (foundKeyAndValue)
        {
            dictRemove(eventData.pointerId);
        }
    }

    void routeOption(PointerEventData eventData, PointerEventType evType)
    {
        UpdateRaycaster();
        if (WholeScreenPointer.Instance.simulateUIEvent)
        {
            //Loop Through All GraphicRaycaster(UI) and throw Raycast to each one
            for (int i = 0; i < grRayCast.Count; i++)
            {
                //Throw Raycast to all UI elements in the position(eventData)
                grRayCast[i].Raycast(eventData, resultList);
                sendArtificialUIEvent(grRayCast[i], eventData, evType);
            }
            //Reset Result
            resultList.Clear();
        }

        if (WholeScreenPointer.Instance.simulateCollider2DEvent)
        {
            //Loop Through All Collider 2D (Sprite Renderer) and throw Raycast to each one
            for (int i = 0; i < phy2dRayCast.Count; i++)
            {
                //Throw Raycast to all UI elements in the position(eventData)
                phy2dRayCast[i].Raycast(eventData, resultList);
                sendArtificialUIEvent(phy2dRayCast[i], eventData, evType);
            }
            //Reset Result
            resultList.Clear();
        }

        if (WholeScreenPointer.Instance.simulateColliderEvent)
        {
            //Loop Through All Normal Collider(3D/Mesh Renderer) and throw Raycast to each one
            for (int i = 0; i < phyRayCast.Count; i++)
            {
                //Throw Raycast to all UI elements in the position(eventData)
                phyRayCast[i].Raycast(eventData, resultList);
                sendArtificialUIEvent(phyRayCast[i], eventData, evType);
            }
            //Reset Result
            resultList.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void routeDragEvent(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        routeOption(eventData, PointerEventType.Drag);
    }

    public void routePointerDownEvent(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        routeOption(eventData, PointerEventType.Down);
    }

    public void routePointerUpEvent(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        routeOption(eventData, PointerEventType.Up);
    }

    public void UpdateRaycaster()
    {
        convertToList(FindObjectsOfType<GraphicRaycaster>(), grRayCast);
        convertToList(FindObjectsOfType<Physics2DRaycaster>(), phy2dRayCast);
        convertToList(FindObjectsOfType<PhysicsRaycaster>(), phyRayCast);
    }

    //To avoid ToList() function
    void convertToList(GraphicRaycaster[] fromComponent, List<GraphicRaycaster> toComponent)
    {
        //Clear and copy new Data
        toComponent.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < fromComponent.Length; i++)
        {
            toComponent.Add(fromComponent[i]);
        }
    }

    //To avoid ToList() function
    void convertToList(Physics2DRaycaster[] fromComponent, List<Physics2DRaycaster> toComponent)
    {
        //Clear and copy new Data
        toComponent.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < fromComponent.Length; i++)
        {
            toComponent.Add(fromComponent[i]);
        }
    }

    //To avoid ToList() function
    void convertToList(PhysicsRaycaster[] fromComponent, List<PhysicsRaycaster> toComponent)
    {
        //Clear and copy new Data
        toComponent.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < fromComponent.Length; i++)
        {
            toComponent.Add(fromComponent[i]);
        }
    }

    //Checks if object is in the dictionary
    private bool dictContains(GameObject obj)
    {
        return pointerIdToGameObject.ContainsValue(obj);
    }

    //Checks if int is in the dictionary
    private bool dictContains(int pointerId)
    {
        return pointerIdToGameObject.ContainsKey(pointerId);
    }

    //Checks if int and object is in the dictionary
    private bool dictContains(int pointerId, GameObject obj)
    {
        return (pointerIdToGameObject.ContainsKey(pointerId) && pointerIdToGameObject.ContainsValue(obj));
    }

    //Adds pointerId and its value to dictionary
    private void dictAdd(int pointerId, GameObject obj)
    {
        pointerIdToGameObject.Add(pointerId, obj);
    }

    //Removes pointerId and its value from dictionary
    private void dictRemove(int pointerId)
    {
        pointerIdToGameObject.Remove(pointerId);
    }

    public enum PointerEventType
    {
        Drag, Down, Up
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

**1**.Attach the `WholeScreenPointer` script to an empty GameObject or the Camera.

**2**.To receive any event in the scene, simply implement `IDragHandler`, `IPointerDownHandler`, `IPointerUpHandler` in any script then call `WholeScreenPointer.Instance.registerGameObject(this.gameObject);` once. Any event from the screen will now be sent to that script. Don't forget to unregister in the `OnDisable()` function.

For example, attach `Test` to any GameObject you want to receive touch events:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    void Start()
    {
        //Register this GameObject so that it will receive events from WholeScreenPointer script
        WholeScreenPointer.Instance.registerGameObject(this.gameObject);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Dragging: ");
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Down: ");
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Up: ");
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        WholeScreenPointer.Instance.unRegisterGameObject(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

You only need to call `WholeScreenPointer.Instance.registerGameObject(this.gameObject);` if you want to receive event anywhere on the screen. If you just want to receive event from current Object, then you don't have to call this. If you do, you will receive multiple events.

*Other Important functions:*

Enable WholeScreen Event - `WholeScreenPointer.Instance.enablewholeScreenPointer(true);`

Disable WholeScreen Event - `WholeScreenPointer.Instance.enablewholeScreenPointer(false);`
Finally, this can be improved more.

Comment: An amazing idea to send them forward!

Comment: Wait - one small point.  As I mentioned to Gökhan above: You know how on the panel you use an invisible image, because Unity forgot to make a Touchable component. THERE'S A COMMON BETTER SOLUTION FOR THAT NOW! stackoverflow.com/a/36892803/294884  Just use a `Touchable` anywhere you would use an "invisible image because Unity forgot Touchable"

Comment: I clicked the bounty here since this answer is so extensive and only a few minutes left in the bounty, cheers men!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I looked at the Touchable stuff and don't understand how it works. It there any function you have to override to detect a touch?

Comment: Very simple: in your example, you attach an `Image` component, with Alpha zero - right?  Very simply: (1) delete that `Image`-alpha-zerp component (2) replace it with a `Touchable`.  It's that simple.  (Override, change, modify absolutely nothing.)

Comment: One critical thing: as it explains at length on that page. In particular: imagine a "BetterButton" which is simply `Button` with one `Touchable` component and no other components whatsoever.  The cool thing is you can just *drop that underneath* anything at all on your UI, and "make" that thing a button. Normally in Unity you have a "button" and the image / animation / whatever goes "under" the button - correct? But if you use a "BetterButton" you can just "drop the buttonness on anything".  This is often a far easier way to work / think. So, anything you've made in UI, you can "buttonize" it.

Comment: I just tested this my answer it looks nice. I realized that this is creating a hidden `Text` component in the hood. You won't see this in the Editor but I realized this after doing `GetComponent<Text>().text = "Test";` then zoomed in looked in the Scene View and saw the secret `Text` that was created. The reason you don't see it on default is because there is not text assigned to it yet. But still, it is still a very fast and robust way of creating a hidden UI for clicking.

Comment: For your information, the click detection only worked in the middle of the screen. It requires scaling to work everywhere on the screen. I called the `stretchImageAndConfigAnchor` function from this  answer and provided `this.gameObject` as parameter. I was able to scale it and make it detect click anywhere on the screen. Feel free to update your [answer](stackoverflow.com/a/36892803/294884) with the [updated version](https://justpaste.it/10czh). You can link back to this answer if you want.

Comment: Howdy!  I'm not totally sure what you mean: when you place ANY unity ui element (say, an image or a panel) - then, of course, naturally, obviously, **you have to set that item as you want it** in terms of anchor, position, stretching.  When you use `Touchable` component - of course, naturally, you just do the same.  Often `Touchable` is on a `Button` - of course, naturally, you would be setting the position and so on of the `Button` on the canvas. (Whether it is small, large, whatever.)...

Comment: I will take a look at it.

Comment: In the `forwardPointerDownEvent()` method you forward the event via `ExecuteEvents.Execute`.  But then inside `eventRouter.routePointerDownEvent()` you forward the event via `ExecuteEvents.Execute` again?  Why does this need to happen twice?